# In express, show error if database connection fails?

Tags: node.js, express

In my node express server, I want to throw an error if I can't reach the database to run the sql query.  However it is not working.

```
const findUserByEmail  = (email, cb) => {
    return  mc.query('SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE email = ?',[email], (err, row) => {
        cb(err, row);
    });
}
```

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const form_password = req.body.password;    
    findUserByEmail(email, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ "message": 'Database error!', "status": '500' });
        res.status(200).send({ "user": email, "message": 'Success!', "status": '200' });
   });
});
```

When I run a curl test on the route, instead of the error, I get:

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

Comment: Not sure catching internal server error makes sense in your endpoint.  You should catch it in your index.js as a general error that could mean database is not reachable as you want. It is not a problem with your endpoint but the application.

Comment: How would I catch the error before the routes?

Comment: Are you opening a `connection to SQL` while starting your `server`?

Comment: I'm doing this:
`const mc = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.dbhost,
    user: process.env.dbuser,
    password: process.env.dbpassword,
    database: process.env.dbdatabase,
    port: process.env.dbport
});`

Comment: Do you do `mc.connect()` or no?

Comment: No, I do not do `mc.connect()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in index.js

```
import router from './routes';
const app = express();
app.use(router);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  return res.status(err.status || 500).json({
    error: {
      message: err.message,
      error: {},
    },
    status: false,
  });
});
```

Based on the discussion, you should be doing this in your db connection file.

```
// connect to database
db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Connected to database');
});
```

Comment: I was wanting more of an error on the route, so I can tell if the database is down.  I tried this, and still got  `{"message": "Internal server error"}`

Comment: See edited. You must have initialized the router in express app in index.js

Comment: Does this go before or after my routes?

Comment: After your router.

Comment: Put it after the router, and still threw the same error.  That could be the correct error, but I want to use a custom error when I can't connect to the database. (see original POST route above)

Comment: update you post with your index.js and database connection files.